# C# multiple custom app.config files in Solutions Explorer

Tags: c#, app-config

I have several custom app.config files and they point directly to my Active Solutions Configurations. They seem to work fine, but the last two I added App.Davivienda.config and App.Futura.config do not appear under the App.config tree. They work fine, but why are they not showing there?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they are not showing hierarchically is that your IDE (presumably Visual Studio) didn't know theses files are related. It's simple to solve this.

Open the `.csproj` file and look at the entries your new files created.

They should have been created with a `<DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>` tag.

If not, change your `.csproj`, and re-open it.

They should look like this:

```
<Content Include="App.Futura.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Comment: Worked! Now what is the proper way of adding these files so they get recognized automatically?

Comment: That's a good question. I never focused on having vs work with nesting properly,... but you could open a new question for that :)